# Is there a way to elegantly type fields of an object literal without typing the object literal itself?

Tags: typescript

Let's assume I have these 2 types:

```
type Foo = {
  foo: string
}

type Bar = {
  bar: number
}
```

Is there a way to type individual fields of an object literal (I'm looking for the right syntax if it exists), without creating a wrapper type?

**This is what I want to avoid:**

```
type Wrapper = {
  a: Foo
  b: Bar
}

const x: Wrapper = {
  a: { foo: 'foo' },
  b: { bar: 123 }
}
```

**This is what I'm trying to do:**

```
const x = {
  // x.a should be of type Foo, enforced by the compiler
  a: { foo: 'foo' },
  // x.b should be of type Bar, enforced by the compiler
  b: { bar: 123 }
}
```

**What I considered, but is not suitable:**

1. Using a `Record` type makes no sense, as I lose the individual fields and their individual types:

```
const x: Record<string, Foo | Bar> = {
  a: { foo: 'foo' },
  b: { bar: 123 }
}
```

2. Type casting (or whatever its called in TS) is also not suitable, as now I loose compiler checks and content assist. At least with this version the type of `x` is correct:

```
const x = {
  a: { foo: 'foo' } as Foo,
  b: { bar: 123 } as Bar
}
```

Comment: How do you associate `a` with `Foo` and `b` with `Bar` without a wrapper type which holds this information? Why is `b` not `Foo`?

Comment: @TobiasS. I'm not sure if I worded it well, but I want to associate `a` with `Foo` in the literal definition, not externally. I marked it as duplicate, as I just found that the `<Type>` operator does this: `const x = { a: <Foo> { foo: 'foo' } }`

Comment: But that is the same as using `as`. There Is no difference

Comment: Retracted the close vote, as with `const x = { a: <Foo> { foo: 'foo' } }` I still lose type checking. Going to keep it open, maybe there is a better alternative.

Comment: @TobiasS. only difference I found is content assist working properly, but you are right, it's still doing the same in terms of losing proper type checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the [`satisfies`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920) operator which will be rolled out in [TypeScript 4.9](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920). It allows to preserve the *literal type* while still type checking with some constraint.

```
const x = {
  a: { foo: "223" },
  b: { bar: 123 }
} satisfies Record<string, Foo | Bar>

x.a.foo // string
x.b.bar // number
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAYgewTAvDA3sGMBmSBcMAziAE4CWAdgObAC+woksAQgIamoZYwBGHhSgFcAtryil6jAMYJKJGAA8umbG0LpcBGACIATHoDMOmHQA0PXhr4CYARiOn6xNiHJEc5KERgAlKLKkACYAPCQUNGbwSDAAPjDspAB8jIoAdGxpeMgA9DnEZFS06bxp-Jx5MMJiEkA)